# Java : Proper way a method() should handle a bad call

Tags: java, return

I am often confronted to this question. Let's see a quick example, I got this simple method : It retrieves the position of a `String` in a `String[]`.

```
public int getStringPosition(String s, String[] text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].equals(s)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return text.length;
}
```

But what if the String isn't in the array? Here, it returns the size of the array (an `int` that couldn't come from a normal use of the method). It could as well return `-1`. I wish it would return null but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Anyway, this method will be used in the same class by some other methods. My question is pretty general, **how to handle the cases where you can't return what is expected?**

Comment: Throw Exceptions...

Comment: And what should the exception do? How to warn the user of the method and still let him continue the flow of his program?

Comment: Despite that what @Hackerdarshi said, the other way, how the `String` methods do work for example, could also be returning `-1`, like for example `String#indexOf`, if you return primitive types.

Comment: @Fitz, by catching the exception in case it is thrown, like with all exceptions :)

Comment: @Jite Yes, I know about exceptions! ^^
I am asking, what should it do, now how to do it. :)

Comment: @KevinEsche Yes, I thought of that too.

Comment: @Fitz in the end i´d say there is no general rule on what you should do, the most important part here is to provide the information what it does in the case with the javadoc. Take one approach, stick to it so the style what it does return doesn´t change and notify the user of these methods about this behavior with a proper documentation.

Comment: @KevinEsche Ok, I'll stick to my decision.

Comment: @Jite Did you mean the user had to catch the exception? In that case, sorry I didn't understand. Yes, that seems to be a solution too!

Comment: @Fitz Yes. Your code throws the exception, and the part which calls the method catches it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the inability to find the string constitutes an *error*, an *exceptional condition*, then you should throw some exception to the caller. E.g.,

```
throw new RuntimeException("String not found");
```

If the inability to find the string is a normal situation that the caller would want to handle in the normal flow of the code, then you should use a special return value. For this type of search method, no normal return value could be negative, and the convention is to return `-1`, as [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) and [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) do. If you follow that convention you could actually implement your method body with a single line:

```
return java.util.Arrays.asList(text).indexOf(s);
```

Note: That change treats `null` a bit differently. There are three things that could be null in your method: the search string, the array, and the elements of the array. Your current code throws a `NullPointerException` if passed a null array, or when it encounters a null element, but silently ignores a null search string. By deferring to `List.indexOf`, all the array elements are allowed to be null too, allowing for searching for a null value within the array. It's probably a harmless difference here, but a well-designed method considers such questions. For example, you might prefer to treat a null search string as invalid input and immediately throw an exception in that case.

A fully documented public method would also consider the case of multiple matching elements within the array: should it return the lowest matching index, or any matching index? If any index is acceptable, must it consistently return the same index for repeat invocations with the same arguments? (A hypothetical multithreaded search implementation could easily defeat the "obvious" assumption of returning the lowest index, because you can't predict which CPU core will find a match first.)

Also consider that the method could be declared `static`.

Answer (score 5):

If the case that the `s` is not in `text` is not a valid way to call the method, you should throw an Exception e.g. IllegalParameterException.

But if it is ok to call the method this way, you should not throw an Exception because it is a valid expected usage. In this case you could e.g. return `-1`.

But `-1` is in this case a 'magic number' which is kind of **bad practice** so you should declare a constant for that.

```
private static final int STRING_NOT_IN_TEXT=-1;

/**
 * @return first position of 's' in 'text' 
 *         and if 's' is not in 'text' returns NOT_IN_TEXT
 */
public static int getStringPosition(final String s, final String[] text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].equals(s)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return STRING_NOT_IN_TEXT;
}
```

*P.s. You may also want to check if the `text` is `null` and handle this case other than simply let the system throw a `NullPointerReference`.*

Comment: I like that too. I thought of returning `-1` indeed and this seems even better.

Answer (score 4):

It is arbitrary. Some developpers will throw Exceptions, others will return some special values like -1. The most important is to define exactly what your method does in any case, so people that will use your code know what they're working with.

Comment: Ok, so there is no generality. Many methods from Apache POI that I am currently using often return null when I am asking for something while it can be provided. So I can continue to code by testing the null case before. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Take care, testing null only works with non-primitive types such as String, ArrayList, etc. (primitive types being things like int, double, float, etc)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that come to my mind:

a) it is very much valid for methods that return an "index" that points into any sort of sequence to return -1 to indicate "no match found"

b) it *may* also be valid to just throw some runtime exception, like IllegalArgumentException

When thinking about option "b)" it sometimes help to have two methods, like a findIndex() vs. getIndex(); and by convention "find" methods would always throw an exception; whereas the other one would return null/-1 or some other value. But of course, this is then something that you define *locally* for your project/your team/your whatever. In other words: all the people dealing with your code have to understand that calling findXyz() might throw an exception; and that there are other methods that don't throw.

And, as a side note, you should always try to be consistent with "standard solutions". What I mean is; assume your code would be using collections:

```
int getIndex(String stringToSearch, List<String> stringsToSearch) {
  return stringsToSearch.indexOf(stringToSearch);
```

Guess what this will return ... and now ask yourself if you would want your array-based solution to do the same thing as the java standard collections ...

(final side note: yes, my variable names are awfully long, but I still think that a lengthy name is better than "s" ... as the later one doesn't tell you anything about the intended use of those parameters).

Answer (score 2):

Follow common and known coding conventions: your method looks like *String.indexOf(String)* so simply return -1 when the input is not found. Exceptions should be "exceptional" and not finding a String in an array it's not.

If you want something more OO you may implement something like

```
Result search(T something,Set<T> someSet);
```

with the interface Result implemented by the classes *Found* and *NotFound* to be handled differently; in general although this solution looks an overkill.

Comment: I understand something "more general". But what does OO *exactly* mean? :)

Comment: Object Oriented ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't return null because you are returning a primite type. Return Integer instead and null will be allowed.

Nevertheless, I agree with the commentator above, the exception is the proper way to handle this issues

Comment: I like the return Integer idea. The goal is to let the user continue his program. Many methods from Apache POI that I am currently using often return `null` when I am asking for something while it can be provided. So I can continue to code by testing the null case before.

Comment: But then that may lead to NullPointerException, and eventually, you would need to handle exceptions...

Comment: the user can capture the exception, log it or assign a default value (or whatever he needs) and continue the program.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Yes but in Apache POI, it seems to be left to the user. Is it a good solution? I like it personnaly. `Cell cell = row.getCell(i, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);` often returns null (as an example).

Answer (score 1):

Its a good patern to return null if nothing was found. You can use `Integer` instead of `int`. The `Integer`  class wraps a value of the primitive type `int` in an object. An object of type `Integer` contains a single field whose type is `int`. Thats why you can return null if you make it like

```
public Integer getStringPosition(String s, String[] text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the suggestions here, however:

- '-1' is a "magic value" and is often regarded as an anti-pattern
- throwing exceptions for a non-exceptional situation is also regarded as an anti-pattern (and some will say throwing any non-system exception is an anti-pattern)
- Use `Integer` as the return type and return a `null` value. However `null` is also seen as an anti-pattern (google "null the billion dollar mistake")

If you don't mind the above then go ahead and use one of the options (all are used frequently by a lot of programmers)

You could also use a Optional/Maybe/Option type

```
public Optional<Integer> getStringPosition(String s, String[] text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].equals(s)) {
            Optional.of(i);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

`Optional` is available in Java 8. If you are using an older version, you can use one of the many available implementations (e.g, https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)